# Why are the sets $En$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading the proof of the **monotone convergence theorem** presented in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* but I did not understand the following statement in the proof:

Define $E_n = \{x: f_n(x) \geq cs(x)\}$. **Each $E_n$ is measurable**.

Why is $E_n$ measurable? Can someone give me at least a sketch of how to prove it?

Comment: what is $cs(x)$ in this case?

Comment: Aren't $f_n$ and $s$ measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Rudin's proof, $c$ means any constant and $s$ is any simple measurable function such that $0\leq s\leq f$. Since any product of two measurable functions, and any sum of two measurable functions are all measurable, we know $f_n-cs$ is measurable. Also, notice that
$$E_n = \{x: f_n(x) \geq cs(x)\}=\{x: f_n(x)-cs(x) \geq 0\}=(f_n-cs)^{-1}([0,\infty))$$
which is measurable, since $[0,\infty)$ is closed (and thus Borel), by Theorem 1.12 in the book.

Comment: You can also see this (quick) answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946791/i-do-not-understand-why-e-n-is-measurable-in-this-proof?rq=1